# How to change local file favicon in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I often open local (to my system) HTML files in Chrome, and they end up showing a generic "file" icon. In Chrome 69, this icon is nearly invisible (see tabs 2 and 3 in the picture below):

[image: Chrome tabs screenshot]

Is there any way I can change the icon for local `file:\\\` URLs in Chrome? I'd like something that's more visible...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30037071/4645236 

Seems like you can just place a favicon.ico file in your downloads folder and it will pull that icon.

Comment: That's interesting, but it means I would have to add the necessary favicon markup to all my local HTML files. I'd ideally like to change the placeholder icon they use for sites with no favicon...

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644684/do-you-have-to-include-link-rel-icon-href-favicon-ico-type-image-x-icon) to your local html files. You can also use Addons like [Bookmark Favicon Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-favicon-changer/acmfnomgphggonodopogfbmkneepfgnh/related).